# MS Access merge two tables

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I need to create a new table base on two tables. I have a database in ms access and need to migrate.

```
               tableT                                          tableS

  ID   CustID   DATE   Exp1   Exp2              ID   CustID   DATE   Tem1   Tem2
  --------------------------------              ---------------------------------
  1       1    1/1/00   5      5                1       1    1/1/00   3      4
  2       2    1/1/00   1      3                2       2    1/1/00   5      0
  3       1    3/1/00   3      2                3       1    5/1/00   0      3
  4       3    4/1/00   4      1                4       3    6/1/00   0      0
```

Desired output table `tableNew`:

```
  ID   CustID   DATE   Exp1   Exp2  Tem1   Tem2
  ---------------------------------------------
  1       1    1/1/00   5      5     3      4
  2       2    1/1/00   1      3     5      0
  3       1    3/1/00   3      2           
  4       3    4/1/00   4      1     
  5       1    5/1/00                0      3
  6       3    6/1/00                0      0
```

If I use outer join, I will not get the output I need.

Any idea or help.

Comment: Post your query, expected output and the current output

Comment: I guess using FULL JOIN will give the correct result.

Comment: @Ankit I will give a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a `full join`.  You can emulate this in MS Access using:

```
select t.CustID, t.DATE, t.Exp1, t.Exp2, s.tem1, s.tem2
from TableT as t left outer join
     tableS as s
     on t.CustId = s.CustId and t.date = s.date
union all
select s.CustID, s.DATE, null, null, s.tem1, s.tem2
from tableS as s left outer join
     tableT as t
     on t.CustId = s.CustId and t.date = s.date
where t.CustId is null;
```

Comment: I think you mean UNION instead of UNION ALL.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai . . . No.  I mean `UNION ALL`.  The second query gets the rows that are NOT returned by the first.